# C++ - inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was expecting the following code snippet to give compile error since derived class will not have `priv_var` which I am trying to access in `pub_fun()`. But it compiled and I got below mentioned output. Can someone explain the theory behind this?

```
class base {

private:
  int priv_var = 90;

public:
  int pub_fun();

} b;

class derived : public base {
} d;

int base::pub_fun() { cout << priv_var << "\n"; }

int main() {
  d.pub_fun();
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
90
```

Comment: Note: Your program has undefined behavior since `int base::pub_fun()` does not return an `int` as declared.

Answer (score 3):

It compiles since the method `pub_fun` is declared in the base class. That is the reason it has access to the private member `priv_var`. If you had created a method in `derived` and attempted to access `priv_var` you would have seen a compile time error.

Comment: But I am using derived class object 'd.pub_fun();'. So, how this access is resolved. I can understand priv_var access using 'd.base ::pub_fun();' but not with 'd.pub_fun();.

Comment: Unless you are overiding a function it in the derived class the function call is done in the base class which has access to private variables of that base class.

Comment: The function is positioned in the base class, even if you use the derived class. The derived class can define its own methods, that will then live in the derived class, and these would not have access to `priv_var`. So in other words the part of your class instance that lives in `base` have access to the private space of `base`.

Comment: @moonshines Only `virtual` member functions can be overridden. A method in the derived class with the same name as method(s) in the base class is _hiding_ the base class method(s) with that name.

Comment: If you followed your logic, @Mr.Bala, nothing from the baseclass would be available in the derived class. However, that's simply not how C++ operates. In C++, the derived class extends the base class, so it has everything from the base and whatever it provides on top.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Class `derived` has access to public (and protected) members of class `base`, by the rules of public inheritance.

**2.** Members of class `base` have access to all other `base` members, because they belong to the same class.

`d.pub_fun();` is valid because of **1.** and `int base::pub_fun() { cout << priv_var << "\n"; }` is valid because of **2.** so everything compiles and works without a problem.

> *I was expecting the following code snippet to give compile error since derived class will not have `priv_var` which I am trying to access in `pub_fun()`.*

You are conflating two separate steps into one here. The `derived` class does indeed not have access to `base::priv_var`, but `derived` never attempts to use `base::priv_var`. All that `derived d;` does is call the public member function `pub_fun()`. From there on it is a matter of `pub_fun` implementation, which `derived` needs not know or care about. In your example, the implementation of `pub_fun` happens to use a private `base` variable, which it is perfectly fine to do since it is a member function of the same `base` class.

In other cases, class `derived` could be your code, and `base` could be a library class to which you don't even have the source code. You could always call public member functions from `base` even though you would have no idea what their implementation uses internally.